# Conflicting return type from constexpr virtual method?

Tags: c++, virtual, constexpr

I have the following code that won't compile. The compiler thinks that the return values differ which I fail to see.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:15,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:15,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:15,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:15,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Cstring_view%3E%0A%23include+%3Ccstdio%3E%0A%0Astruct+base%0A%7B%0A++++virtual+constexpr+auto+delimiter()+const+noexcept+-%3E+std::string_view+%3D+0%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+derived+:+public+base%0A%7B%0A++++constexpr+auto+delimiter()+const+noexcept+override+-%3E+std::string_view+%7B+return+%22/%22%3B+%7D%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B+%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:57.59791122715404,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-Wall+-Os+--std%3Dc%2B%2B20%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),l:%274%27,m:41.3677130044843,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,m:58.632286995515706,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),k:42.40208877284596,l:%273%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

```
#include <string_view>
#include <cstdio>

struct base
{
    virtual constexpr auto delimiter() const noexcept -> std::string_view = 0;
};

struct derived : public base
{
    constexpr auto delimiter() const noexcept override -> std::string_view { return "/"; }
};

int main() { }
```

Idk if I have maybe placed my keywords in the wrong order. It *does* compile without the `override` keyword.

Error:

```
<source>:11:47: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
   11 |     constexpr auto delimiter() const noexcept override -> std::string_view { return "/"; }
      |                                               ^~~~~~~~
      |                                                       ;
<source>:11:56: error: expected unqualified-id before '->' token
   11 |     constexpr auto delimiter() const noexcept override -> std::string_view { return "/"; }
      |                                                        ^~
<source>:11:20: error: conflicting return type specified for 'virtual constexpr auto derived::delimiter() const'
   11 |     constexpr auto delimiter() const noexcept override -> std::string_view { return "/"; }
      |                    ^~~~~~~~~
<source>:6:28: note: overridden function is 'virtual constexpr std::string_view base::delimiter() const'
    6 |     virtual constexpr auto delimiter() const noexcept -> std::string_view = 0;
      |
```

Comment: Your demo fail to compile with incorrect syntax. I don't see your claimed error. If I fix the syntax error, [it compiles](https://godbolt.org/z/Y4GveEear).

Comment: @PasserBy  I know that. What's wrong?

Comment: Oh I understand what's going on now. You skipped the first page of errors and then picked one at random, which becomes confusing as hell. If you looked at the first error "error: expected ';' at end of member declaration", you'll realize it's a syntax error.

Comment: Fixed version of your code : https://godbolt.org/z/c7bKdPqhG (thanks I learned today that virtual functions can be used in constexpr didn't realize that could be done too)

Comment: @PasserBy Ok sorry I thought this was the culprit so I selected this error. But what is the syntax error? Why can I not use override keyowrd here?

Comment: The syntax error is that `const noexcept` should be before the trailing return value.

Comment: It's... syntax. There's not much more to it other than C++ says so.

Comment: @PepijnKramer Yes it's actually quite handy :)

Comment: @glades Yes! Funny how I sometimes can use features of C++ for years and then find out there is even more :)

Comment: I can't see how this question is a "typo" (it's a misunderstanding of how to use `override`), and it is **clearly reproducible**. Whether or not it has been "resolved in a way less likely to help future readers" is not really for me to say. However, I have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *I have maybe placed my keywords in the wrong order*

Yes, that's your problem. Put the `override` token *after* the trailing return type:

```cpp
struct derived : public base {
    auto constexpr delimiter() const noexcept -> std::string_view override { return "/"; }
};
```

This is because the `-> std::string_view` is part of the *function declarator* and the `override` specifier must be placed *immediately after* that declarator (and *just before* the function body, if present).

More details on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override), and [see here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function) for more on "function declarators".

In terms of the C++ Standard, `override` is one of the two "virtual specifiers" (along with `final`); the best citation I can make from [this Draft C++17 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4713.pdf) is from "Appendix A - Grammar Summary", where a function definition is described in the following terms:

> ##### A.7 Declarators          [gram.decl]
>
> …
> *function-definition:*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> declarator virt-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> function-body*
>      *attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> decl-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub> declarator requires-clause function-body*

This makes it clear that the *virt-specifier-seq* (one or more of `virtual` and `final`) is **not** part of the *declarator* and should be between that and the function body. In [this 'latest' online Draft Standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#nt:function-definition), the relevant section is much the same, with the added benefit of links in the various parts of the function definition.

Comment: Thanks! But this makes no sense X_x

Comment: @glades In what sense does it make no sense? That's how the C++ syntax for `override` is specified.

Comment: @glades It's not a matter of what *you* consider what's meaningful, but what the *standard* says (well, in a way then, what the standard committee considers meaningful...). `const` and `noexcept` are both properties of the function, leaving them out alters the function itself. That's why they need to be placed where they are, and a trailing return type follows these. Adding override or not has no influence on the function, it's just a help for the developer to prevent errors. So it goes to a different place...

Comment: @glades I can speak in 4 human languages and these make **lot less** sense. Basically just noise made by whistling through meat.

Comment: @AdrianMole It sure is. But semantically the override keyword specifies that this function implements a virtual function from the base class. It doesn't have any relations to the return type, it's a function attribute just like noexcept so I would argue it should be placed where noexcept is placed.

Comment: @glades `override` is *not* an attribute, like `noexcept`. I *think* it's called a **virtual-specifier** in the C++ Standard. I'm looking for where it's use is defined but, so far, I have failed to find that. As you have discovered, you can omit the specifier and your code will compile (but the function will *still* be an override of the base class version). The specifier just makes writing safer code easier.

Comment: @glades - You aren't putting it *on the return type*. You are placing it after the function declarator.

Comment: *"the `override` keyword"*: [`override`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) is NOT a [keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword). (it can be used as regular identifier).